# Rounding number from API - VB.NET - CultureInfo

Tags: vb.net, rounding

I am currently using this formula to round a number that I am getting from an API

```
 Dim editedRatio As Decimal = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(growth), 0)
 returnRatio = editedRatio.ToString("0,0,,", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
 returnRatio = "$" & returnRatio.Substring(0, returnRatio.Length - 2) & "B"
```

The result is `$44,9B`

I am attempting to get back `$44.9B`

I've tried adjusting the to `editedRatio.ToString("0.0,,")` but it ends up breaking the rounding formula for example : 44954308000

Is there a way to convert the comma to a decimal point?

Comment: What is the input? Why don't you use proper formatting and `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: The input is 44954308000, I am using the existing code that was in the project. Not sure what the proper format for cultureinfo is.

Comment: How is `44954308000` supposed to turn into `44.6`? Maybe `44594308000` could, if you knew what this number represents and what the conversion rule is. Are you just taking what's on the left and on the right of the last thousands separator?

Comment: Sorry you are correct, as I made a typo. 44954308000 should turn into 44.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

Since it looks like you want to return a formatted *number* which is the result of the conversion of the original input string to a `decimal` representation, where the initial value is divided by `(1000 ^ [thousands separators])`.

It's not actually clear if this is the expected value, but the division:

```
editedRatio = Decimal.Divide(editedRatio, CDec(1000 ^ (growth.Length \ 3)))
```

can be modified in simply:

```
editedRatio = Decimal.Divide(editedRatio, (1000 ^ 3)
```

if this is instead the expected output. Or any other specific value defined by the *conversion rule*.

**`Note1`**: the decimal is converted to string using `{N2}` since `{N1}` causes rounding
**`Note2`**: you could also use `new CultureInfo("en-Us")` and `{C2}` format instead of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and `{N2}` to insert the `$` symbol. But I'm not sure `$` is  actually meant to represent currency here.

With `growth = "44954308000"`:

```
Dim editedRatio As Decimal = 0.0D
Dim returnRatio As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()

If Decimal.TryParse(growth, editedRatio) Then
    editedRatio = Decimal.Divide(editedRatio, CDec(1000 ^ (growth.Length \ 3)))
    returnRatio.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "${0:N2}", editedRatio)
    returnRatio.Remove(returnRatio.Length - 1, 1).Append("B")
End If

Console.WriteLine(returnRatio)
```

Prints:  `$44.9B`

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub my_method01()
    Dim returnratio As String = "44954308000"
    Dim editedRatio As Decimal = Decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(returnratio), 0)
    returnratio = editedRatio.ToString("0,0,,", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    returnratio = "$" & returnratio.Substring(0, returnratio.Length - 2) & "B"
    'Displays: "$44.9B"
End Sub
```

I hope it likes to you. Thank you very much. Happy codding! :)